# Soundcloud script (VBS) to get related songs in Foobar playlist

Tags: vbscript, soundcloud

<sub>The script was not written by me - it is a .vbs script for use in Foobar2000</sub>

https://gist.github.com/rornor/4d06d0994c1b8ae61ef5

The script queries the soundcloud.api and gets a list of songs based on a user or group. A dialogue pops up and asks for a username, search term, group, or URL, and it will load a group of songs into a temporary .pls file that it deletes after closing the player. I haven't much experience with .vbs so I can't give much information, but I can give the script here:

Screenshot of dialogue:

[[image]

<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLUBA.jpg)

### My question is

I would like it to build a related playlist like that the website does, so I choose one song and it loads the list of related songs into my Foobar Playlist. Is there a specific url I can load so it does that, or can I have it load from the API somewhere?

Comment: Halosheep, have you gotten your ClientID and registered your your app?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an undocumented `/related` endpoint that can be used on a track object to get its "related" tracks

I'll be using this track as an example, which has an `id` of `107686148`: https://soundcloud.com/maddecent/grandtheft-mobbin-feat

```
HTTP GET: https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/tracks/107686148/related?client_id={YOUR_CLIENT_ID}
```

The response from this `api-v2` endpoint is an array of `track` objects which matche the related tracks shown in your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

try this if you're working with WScript:

```
Dim Shell
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run "soundcloud.com/tracks/00000/related?client_id=(your client id)"
```

that's a basic running mechanism in WScript but I'd like you to clarify a bit as I'm not sure what you mean by "`loading songs into your playlist through vbscript`".